# SQL query that throws away rows that are older & satisfy a condition?

Tags: sql, mysql

Issuing the following query:

```
  SELECT t.seq, 
         t.buddyId, 
         t.mode, 
         t.type, 
         t.dtCreated 
    FROM MIM t 
   WHERE t.userId = 'ali' 
ORDER BY t.dtCreated DESC;
```

...returns me 6 rows.

```
+-------------+------------------------+------+------+---------------------+
|         seq | buddyId                | mode | type | dtCreated           |
+-------------+------------------------+------+------+---------------------+
|          12 | abcdefghij25@gmail.com |    2 |    1 | 2009-09-14 12:39:05 |
|          11 | abcdefghij25@gmail.com |    4 |    1 | 2009-09-14 12:39:02 |
|          10 | op_eee_81@hotmail.com  |    1 |   -1 | 2009-09-14 12:39:00 |
|           9 | abcdefghij25@gmail.com |    1 |   -1 | 2009-09-14 12:38:59 |
|           8 | op_eee_81@hotmail.com  |    2 |    1 | 2009-09-14 12:37:53 |
|           7 | abcdefghij25@gmail.com |    2 |    1 | 2009-09-14 12:37:46 |
+-------------+------------------------+------+------+---------------------+
```

I want to return rows based on this condition:

1. If there are duplicate rows with the same **buddyId**, only return me the latest (as specified by **dtCreated**).

So, the query should return me:

```
+-------------+------------------------+------+------+---------------------+
|         seq | buddyId                | mode | type | dtCreated           |
+-------------+------------------------+------+------+---------------------+
|          12 | abcdefghij25@gmail.com |    2 |    1 | 2009-09-14 12:39:05 |
|          10 | op_eee_81@hotmail.com  |    1 |   -1 | 2009-09-14 12:39:00 |
+-------------+------------------------+------+------+---------------------+
```

I've tried with no success to use a UNIQUE function but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should only return the most recent entry for each userId.

```
SELECT a.seq
     , a.buddyId
     , a.mode
     , a.type
     , a.dtCreated
FROM mim AS [a]
JOIN (SELECT MAX(dtCreated) FROM min GROUP BY buddyId) AS [b]
     ON a.dtCreated = b.dtCreated
     AND a.userId = b.userId
WHERE userId='ali'
ORDER BY dtCreated DESC;
```

Comment: I knew the trick with Where userID = (select ....) but it will run subquery for every line. This is better solution. +1

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot: A subquery doesn't execute for every line in the WHERE clause; a SELECT in the SELECT clause (IE: SELECT t.col, (SELECT...), ...) **will**...